# Linux script command terminates as soon as it started

Tags: shell

I am uisng script command to execute a binary. As soon as the execution starts , it ends the next moment. Please see the logs below

```
08:46:01 + script -c '/home/jenkins/workspace/slack-bot-test/s3-storage-e2e-test -kubeconfig /clusters/s3-e2e-test/kube-config-s3-e2e-test.yml -host https://xxx:23530' log.txt
08:46:01 Script started, file is log.txt
08:46:01 Script done, file is log.txt
```

Comment: Well it's kind of impossible to help you since we don't know the contents of the script.

Comment: Huge lines of shell code. But those have exit statements which gets executed when some conditions fail. But those conditions never failed in my test scenario.